# Surface element over sphere in Cartesian

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

Suppose I want to evaluate a vector function f(x,y,z) over a hemisphere in Cartesian coordinates.
$$\int \vec f.\vec{dS}$$
Over $x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z>0$.
What would be my surface element. My research tells it should be something like
$dS=dxdy \hat k + dydz \hat i + dxdz \hat j$.
Then dot product would give me something like $f_x dydz + f_y dxdz+ f_z dxdy$. Then how would I set the limits. Is it correct?Pls guide me.

Comment: since intgrating over a sparer you should use the appropriate spheric coordinates,

Comment: Is it not possible in Cartesian?